# Get field value from another table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

In Microsoft Access 2013, I have two tables - `tblStudentInfo` and `tblStudentPayment` and I would like to achieve the following objective.

**Scenario**

```
Fields in tblStudentInfo - [ StudentID (pri key), Name, OtherInfo ]
Fields in tblStudentPayment - [ StudentID, Name, PaymentDate ]
```

**Objective**

If `StudentID` is stated in `tblStudentPayment`, the `Name` will be populated based on `tblStudentInfo`.

**Example**

```
 Row 1 of tblStudentInfo = [ 1234, Bobby, otherinfo ]
```

If someone enters `StudentID` into `tblStudentPayment`, the `Name` in `tblStudentPayment` will be `Bobby`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you link the tables? Instead of Name in tblStudentPayment, have 'StudentLookup', a number that links to StudentID in tblStudentInfo.

Comment: It's because a given student can have more than one payment date. It will create lots of duplicates in the tblStudentInfo.